# Sending push notifications through asp.net windows phone 8

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-8, push-notification

Am trying to send push notifications to windows phone 8 using asp.net. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, you need to specify whether this is for an app, or a webpage... but I still have answers for you

A simple google search for "asp.net wp8 push notification" revealed [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202977%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) as the first link. If that page isn't quite what you were looking for, the top 3 links also looked good.

The tutorial walks through it quite nicely, but the basics are,

- you have to open a connection to the push notification service using
  a client app
- then you create a asp.net page that will push information to the app
- and then you run it.

if you are trying to do this from a website (with no client side app), I've used [this](http://madskristensen.net/post/javascript-alertshow%28e2809dmessagee2809d%29-from-aspnet-code-behind) implementation of a javascript alert in the past. On my android phone, it looks and works just like a popup notification from an app. I'm thinking it'll be the same for WP8. Note... this will only work if the user is actively viewing the webpage in the browser (not exactly a push notification).